# How can I pass arguements to child fields in Apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, gql

I'm trying to build a graphql interface that deals with data from different regions and for each region there's a different DB.

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
TypeDefs= gql`
  type Player {
    account_id: Int
    nickname: String
    clan_id:Int
    clan_info:Clan

 }
  type Clan{
    name: 
  }
```

So right now I can request player(region, id), and this will pull up the player details no issues there.

But the issue is that Clan_info field also requires the region from the parent, so the resolver would look like clan_info({clan_id}, **region**).

Is there any way to pass down the region from parent to child field? I know I can add it to the details of the player, but would rather not since there would be millions of records and every field counts

Comment: no, "resolver would look like" `clan_info(parent, args, context, info)` ... `args` will be empty as probably no args (in query - of course, you can pass it explicitly) for that field ... `parent` can contain `clan_id` and `region` if Player resolver will attach `region` arg to own returned [read from DB] player object

Comment: I found the solution, when Player resolver returns I added an extra field of region. This way I don't need to save it in db and works perfectly